# How to set required attribute for form inputText in play framework 2.5.x

Tags: forms, playframework

I have an input which is wrote in html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title..." name="title" id="title" maxlength="255" data-error="Title must not be empty" required>
```

Now I want to use Helper.inputText to replace the above input. Here is my code:

```
helper.inputText(postForm("title"), 'class -> "form-control", 'placeholder -> "Title...", 'name -> "title", 'maxlength -> 255,
Symbol("data-error") -> "Title must not be empty")
```

I don't know how to set required attribute to that inputText.
Do you have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Constraints are defined in the back-end model.  If you're using Java, it will be something like

```
public class User {
    @Required
    protected String title;

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title= title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

Details: https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaForms#Defining-constraints

Using Scala:

```
val userForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "title" -> nonEmptyText
  )(UserData.apply)(UserData.unapply)
)
```

Details: https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaForms#Defining-constraints-on-the-form

Comment: I'm using bootstrap validation, so input element must have "required" attribute to display a warning. I also validate data at the server side, but in my case, I just want to use bootstrap validation at the client side and display some information to users.

Comment: And if you use `helper.inputText(postForm("title"), 'class -> "form-control", 'placeholder -> "Title...", 'name -> "title", 'maxlength -> 255, Symbol("data-error") -> "Title must not be empty", 'required -> "required")`?  I think the value doesn't actually matter, it just needs the presence of the attribute.